# Site Tagline Scrolling Above Top Navigation

Tags: html, css, web, navigation

Can somone take a look and see why my site tagline when scrolling down the page stays above the navigation and does not go behind.

Here is the css for my tagline

```
#banner-tagline {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 44px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
z-index: 99999;
top: 50%;
}
```

http://jobspark.ca/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `z-index` to 4. You have the top tagline with z-index:5. The one with z-index 5 hides one with 4.

The Z position of each element is considered as `layer ordering` and expressed as an integer representing the stacking order for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your "Z-Index" is set to 9999. It's on the uppermost layer. Set your z-index to -9999.